# Eliminar valores duplicados php

Tags: php, php7, php5

Estoy tratando de eliminar los duplicados que tengo en mi `txt` de emails con `PHP`

Lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

Algo así es el `txt`:

```
    uu7@m.com
uu7@m.com
uu7@m.com
uu7@m.com
uu7@m.com
ttd@t.com
ttd@t.com
```

y este es el código que tengo escrito:

```
$fichero_email = array('copia-emails.txt');
$fichero_salida = 'salida.txt';

    foreach ($fichero_email as $fichero_limpio) {
        $new = file_get_contents($fichero_limpio);
        preg_match_all("/[a-z0-9_\-\+\.]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,4})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i", $new, $resultado);
        foreach ($resultado[0] as $result) {
            echo "<br>$result";
            file_put_contents($fichero_salida, $result, FILE_APPEND);
        }
    }
```

¿Alguna idea que me puedan brindar, para que en la `salida.txt` solo me guarde los emails sin duplicados?

Comment: podrias incluir un ejemplo de tu archivo copia-emails.txt

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear un array con los emails, controlando que en ese array no se introduzcan duplicados, por ejemplo:

```
$fichero_email = array('copia-emails.txt');
$fichero_salida = 'salida.txt';
$mUnique=array();
    foreach ($fichero_email as $fichero_limpio) {
        $new = file_get_contents($fichero_limpio);
        preg_match_all("/[a-z0-9_\-\+\.]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,4})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i", $new, $resultado);
        foreach ( trim($resultado[0]) as $result ) {
            if (!in_array($result, $mUnique)) {
                $mUnique[] = $result;
            }
        }
    }
file_put_contents($fichero_salida, implode(",",$mUnique), FILE_APPEND);
```

Aquí tendrás en `$mUnique` todos los emails. Además sacamos la escritura del bucle, para no estar escribiendo cada vez, sino una sola vez, al final. Usamos `implode` para escribir los datos separados por coma, puedes poner el separador de tu gusto.

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar tener que recorrer una lista para saber si ya fue agregado o no, podrías crear una arreglo asociativo (`$hash`) en el cual:

- Utilizamos como clave el email (`$hash[$email]`)
- Si no esta seteado (`!isset($hash[$email])`) entonces es la primera ocurrencia

#### Ejemplo:

```
$fichero_email = array('copia-emails.txt');
$fichero_salida = 'salida.txt';
$hash = array();

foreach ($fichero_email as $fichero_limpio) {
    $new = file_get_contents($fichero_limpio);
    preg_match_all("/[a-z0-9_\-\+\.]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,4})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i", $new, $resultado);
    foreach (trim($resultado[0]) as $email) {
        if (!isset($hash[$email])) {
            $hash[$email] = true;
            echo "<br>$email";
            file_put_contents($fichero_salida, $email, FILE_APPEND);
        }
    }
}
```